# Azure CosmosDb ru's Calculation in SQL API Query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a collection with ~**10000 documents**, I have fired SQL query to check the Ru's calculation, this query is for dashboard count for a different status.

```
       {
        "entityType": "vehicleStatus",
        "vehicleCheckInId": "8cd93887-ce34-4b1d-87f6-2f36723319a8",
        "email": "bsellarbn@instagram.com",
        "tag": 420,
        "vin": "1C3BC2FB6BN851962",
        "phoneNumber": "549-357-1195",
        "customerName": "Bambie",
        "facilityId": "7f8663b4-5270-4259-ad33-6646ec33cd42",
        "vehicleId": "427c6d23-eb65-40cd-b8fa-f0159063509f",
        "facilityName": "Abc Service Center",
        "roNumber": "RO70-527-0925",
        "vehicleDetail": [
            {
                "make": "Subaru",
                "model": "Outback",
                "trim": "05-387-2180",
                "year": 2018,
                "colorCode": "#6bbede"
            }
        ],
        "advisor": [
            {
                "id": "35d55e01-fbb7-4752-8423-3859f0d46bde",
                "name": "Abc"
            }
        ],
        "techinician": [
            {
                "id": "480b8d19-fc1a-42df-a1e0-d70b35f4d8fb",
                "name": "Bcd"
            }
        ],
        "subQueue": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "queueId": 2,
                "quoteId": "e9e1e0a1-e905-484b-9b32-638f3601bee5",
                "primaryfacilityId": "null",
                "isLatest": "false",
                "CreatedBy": "2d3af542-e6a4-4b3b-b93c-01aa06f77a2c"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "queueId": 2,
                "quoteId": "cbf47904-4549-40bd-9788-c67de5a3da33",
                "primaryfacilityId": "null",
                "isLatest": "false",
                "CreatedBy": "2d3af542-e6a4-4b3b-b93c-01aa06f77a2c"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "queueId": 3,
                "quoteId": "4d6f6d6e-f97d-4875-80bc-0d6f255715a3",
                "primaryfacilityId": "null",
                "isLatest": "false",
                "CreatedBy": "2d3af542-e6a4-4b3b-b93c-01aa06f77a2c"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "queueId": 3,
                "quoteId": "903aeb55-21ef-402f-83d1-3f10c3887cb8",
                "primaryfacilityId": "null",
                "isLatest": "false",
                "CreatedBy": "2d3af542-e6a4-4b3b-b93c-01aa06f77a2c"
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "queueId": 5,
                "quoteId": "060c51a1-31df-4169-bfe7-1270c88a328b",
                "primaryfacilityId": "null",
                "isLatest": "false",
                "CreatedBy": "2d3af542-e6a4-4b3b-b93c-01aa06f77a2c"
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "queueId": 5,
                "quoteId": "92494165-2eee-47dc-9da0-84dd2e5bbe73",
                "primaryfacilityId": "null",
                "isLatest": "false",
                "CreatedBy": "2d3af542-e6a4-4b3b-b93c-01aa06f77a2c"
            },
            {
                "id": 16,
                "queueId": 5,
                "quoteId": "8a73e5e7-5f8a-4be7-bd8f-5f99c2328f68",
                "primaryfacilityId": "c3851f80-0625-46bb-8c3c-78f1418e4caf",
                "isLatest": "false",
                "CreatedBy": "2d3af542-e6a4-4b3b-b93c-01aa06f77a2c"
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "queueId": 5,
                "quoteId": "8b517315-d754-4f04-bcf0-b74958f311ed",
                "primaryfacilityId": "c3851f80-0625-46bb-8c3c-78f1418e4caf",
                "isLatest": "false",
                "CreatedBy": "2d3af542-e6a4-4b3b-b93c-01aa06f77a2c"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "queueId": 4,
                "quoteId": "65056abd-573c-4ede-826d-3c7a9aeeaba7",
                "primaryfacilityId": "c3851f80-0625-46bb-8c3c-78f1418e4caf",
                "isLatest": "false",
                "CreatedBy": "2d3af542-e6a4-4b3b-b93c-01aa06f77a2c"
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "queueId": 4,
                "quoteId": "96d73845-2ba8-4327-b0cc-7580b764f3da",
                "primaryfacilityId": "c3851f80-0625-46bb-8c3c-78f1418e4caf",
                "isLatest": "false",
                "CreatedBy": "2d3af542-e6a4-4b3b-b93c-01aa06f77a2c"
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "queueId": 4,
                "quoteId": "2f24e83d-3cf6-42c9-b50a-4d1a5e68f1f4",
                "primaryfacilityId": "c3851f80-0625-46bb-8c3c-78f1418e4caf",
                "isLatest": "false",
                "CreatedBy": "2d3af542-e6a4-4b3b-b93c-01aa06f77a2c"
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "queueId": 4,
                "quoteId": "04e0142b-ff21-46ca-8346-3e557bd0ba79",
                "primaryfacilityId": "c3851f80-0625-46bb-8c3c-78f1418e4caf",
                "isLatest": "true",
                "CreatedBy": "2d3af542-e6a4-4b3b-b93c-01aa06f77a2c"
            }
        ],
        "createdDate": "2019-12-24 21:57:54",
        "deletedDate": "null",
}
```

```
**Query :** 
SELECT q.queueid,q.id 
FROM c JOIN q IN c.subQueue 
where c.entityType='vehicleStatus' 
and c.facilityId='7f8663b4-5270-4259-ad33-6646ec33cd42' 
and q.queueid=4 and q.id=12 and q.isLatest='true'
```

After Executing this query the Ru's which I notice is 1200 Ru's, which is very high for me and it cost me more, I need to optimize the query or document to attain lower RU consumption but how to do that, because in this document status is actively updating,
and I need to improve the performance of the application, is there any way I can optimize the query or any other solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that there are [many ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips) to improve performance of query,but no direct ways could help you reduce cost without any lost.After all, you have to implement the basic of your business requirements.

As above doc says: The cost associated with each of these operations varies based on the CPU, IO, and memory required to complete the operation which means every sql cost does make sense.

I would suggest you try to add some indexes on specific properties.In addition,please try to split the sql. For example, filter the `entityType` and `facilityId` first, then use join to filter `isLatest` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there would be near death scenario to use joins in Cosmos with that much document querying as compute will be much higher as per your documents in collection, following points you should consider to avoid these type of queries:

- Redefine your document structure if you can by indexing subqueue items as:

  `{
      "entityType": "vehicleStatus",
      "vehicleCheckInId": "8cd93887-ce34-4b1d-87f6-2f36723319a8",
      "email": "bsellarbn@instagram.com",
      "tag": 420,
      "vin": "1C3BC2FB6BN851962",
      "phoneNumber": "549-357-1195",
      "customerName": "Bambie",
      "facilityId": "7f8663b4-5270-4259-ad33-6646ec33cd42",
      "vehicleId": "427c6d23-eb65-40cd-b8fa-f0159063509f",
      "facilityName": "Abc Service Center",
      "roNumber": "RO70-527-0925",
      "vehicleDetail": [
          {
              "make": "Subaru",
              "model": "Outback",
              "trim": "05-387-2180",
              "year": 2018,
              "colorCode": "#6bbede"
          }
      ],
      "advisor": [
          {
              "id": "35d55e01-fbb7-4752-8423-3859f0d46bde",
              "name": "Abc"
          }
      ],
      "techinician": [
          {
              "id": "480b8d19-fc1a-42df-a1e0-d70b35f4d8fb",
              "name": "Bcd"
          }
      ],
      "subQueue": {
          "11": {
              "id": 11,
              "queueId": 4,
              "quoteId": "96d73845-2ba8-4327-b0cc-7580b764f3da",
              "primaryfacilityId": "c3851f80-0625-46bb-8c3c-78f1418e4caf",
              "isLatest": "false",
              "CreatedBy": "2d3af542-e6a4-4b3b-b93c-01aa06f77a2c"
          },
          "10": {
              "id": 10,
              "queueId": 4,
              "quoteId": "2f24e83d-3cf6-42c9-b50a-4d1a5e68f1f4",
              "primaryfacilityId": "c3851f80-0625-46bb-8c3c-78f1418e4caf",
              "isLatest": "false",
              "CreatedBy": "2d3af542-e6a4-4b3b-b93c-01aa06f77a2c"
          },
          "12": {
              "id": 12,
              "queueId": 4,
              "quoteId": "04e0142b-ff21-46ca-8346-3e557bd0ba79",
              "primaryfacilityId": "c3851f80-0625-46bb-8c3c-78f1418e4caf",
              "isLatest": "true",
              "CreatedBy": "2d3af542-e6a4-4b3b-b93c-01aa06f77a2c"
          }
      },
      "createdDate": "2019-12-24 21:57:54",
      "deletedDate": "null",
  }`

which can improve your query as:

```
where q.subQueue["11"] <> null or any appropriate filter.
```

- Secondly, if you want to filter with multiple property of subQueue array items, you should definately consider udf which will filter the per document rather than join,
- Index your querying properties in collection settings,
- Beauty of NOSQL is to store data in any schema so you should optimize the document structure as per your querying need.

Hope this would be suffice for you to get rid of joins in your query.